# Font face shows up correctly on Chrome but not on Safari or Firefox. I even added the formats. What is wrong?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

What am I supposed to do? This is all my code. I'm very new to this so I don't know if I'm doing it correctly but this is what I have reached so far... I have been looking everywhere for the problem and its solution but none of them have worked so far. I would really appreciate some help.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #ff793f">

<title> The Fandomized Shop </title>

<!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
<div class = "navigationBar" style = "font-family: LemonMilklight">
   <li><a href="#home" class ="active"  > Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href = "#shop" >Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#contact" > Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#about"> About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#cart" > Cart </a> </li>
    <span class = "fa fa-search searchIcon"></span>
    
    <div class ="searchBar">
    <li>  <span class = "Clear"> <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search" class = "Search" style="font-family: LemonMilklight"> </span></button> </li>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Slogan -->
<h1 style= "font-family: LemonMilklight"> your one stop shop for everything fandomized</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the font with all its formats. Isn't it supposed to work on Safari and Firefox like this? Is there a setting change I need to do first? Is something wrong with the font? Should I add every format in a different font face? I have been trying to fix it for day to no avail.

### CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LemonMilklight';
    src: url(lemonmilklight-webfont.eot);
    src: url(lemonmilklight-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(lemonmilklight-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
         url(lemonmilklight-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
         url(lemonmilklight-webfont.svg#lemonmilk_lightregular) format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I would really appreciate any help because I am very lost. I was going to continue developing and testing it on Chrome but I realized this will only be a hassle when I try to test it on Safari or Firefox. What are the other ways to fix this?

Comment: Where did you get the fonts from? Do you actually have all those different file types?

Comment: A quick search didn't show me any place to download anything other than a `.ttf`. Did you convert a true type or open type font into `.eot`, `woff` etc?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you actually including the CSS somewhere? I am not seeing a stylesheet in your HTML head. Something like this

2. Per that font-face definition, the font files (.EOT etc) should be located in the same directory as your HTML file.

---

As to why it is working in one browser but not the other - like one of the other commenters suggested, if you only got one of the file formats TTF for example, maybe Chrome is accepting at that a fallback whereas safari and FF won't.